Как настроить клиент OAuth 2.0 для хостинга?
Решил создать Телеграм-бота на C# и в контексте этого бота мне нужна какая-то бд. Я решил воспользоваться гугл-таблицами при помощи Google Sheets API. Я создал сервисный аккаунт, создал клиента OAuth 2.0 (тип клиента указал как десктопное приложение) и в качестве тестовых пользователей указал свою почту и почту самого сервисного аккаунта. В процессе разработки и тестирования я ни с какими проблемами не сталкивался. Но когда пришло время закинут бота на хостинг пришла беда. Я решил закинуть на хостинг по ютубу, через сервис Replit. То, что касается работы самого бота он выполняет, но когда приходит время записывать что что в гугл таблицу, меня перекидывает в гугл что бы я дал ему доступ к таблице. Я вхожу через свой gmail аккаунт и мне выходит проблема что у этого аккаунта нет нужных разрешений, а когда я тестировал приложение в консольке никаких проблем не было. Я так же зашел через мой gmail аккаунт и все было хорошо. Я подозревая что это из за того, что в списке тест.юзеров нет нужного аккаунта через который Replit может получить доступ. Но все же я сомневаюсь. Что делать, не подскажите?
